# Deleting all iterations of numpy in linux

Tags: python, linux, numpy

I need some help. I am using Linux on my Raspberry Pi. I am creating a python program that requires many libraries, and one of them is numpy. It has recently come to my attention that my Pi has many versions of numpy on it, which is not what I want. I've tried to use the simple

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

command in the terminal, but it's only uninstalling one of the many instances of numpy on my computer. Here's how I found out I had a problem:

I made a python program called libcheck.py that said:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
```

and it put out:

```
1.19.5
```

This is not the most recent version, so I ran:

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

and it said that 1.23.1 was successfully installed. However, when I ran libcheck.py again, it put out:

```
1.19.5
```

This led me to use the search tool on my Pi to find all places where numpy is present. I found there were 4. I really want to fully uninstall numpy from my computer so I can install the newest version. Here's my question: what would be the command that would fully uninstall numpy? I'm afraid that manually deleting those folders will do something weird to my computer.

Thank you,
Margorp13

Comment: What version of python are you using to run libcheck.py? What version of python is "pip" linked to?

Comment: when I find python's version, it says 3.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably using cached numpy downloaded earlier.
The version can be specified when installing as:

```
pip install numpy==1.23.1
```

or instruct pip to not use cache directory

```
pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
```